# Magento sort categories database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

I have this tree of categories in magento with main>subcat>subcat1. 3 levels. I want to sort the first two levels with custom order and the subcategories of the second level alphabetically.
I found catalog_category_entity table and I am sorting each categories one by one.
The problem is that I have 900 categories and this is a waste of time.
I don't know about databases but is there some queries:
1)to select main categories so I can order them custom
2)to select subcategories for same reason
3)to select the third level of categories and sort the automatically in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these queries on the database to achieve your goals.

Query to select main categories:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity` WHERE `level` = 1;
```

Query to select subcategories:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity` WHERE `level` = 2;
```

To sort alphabetically the third level categories:

```
/* define a variable */
SET @rownum=0;

/* Pay attention to the attribute_id which must correspond to the Name attribute of the category */
update `catalog_category_entity` cat
join (
    SELECT cce.entity_id
    FROM `catalog_category_entity` cce 
    JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` ccev ON cce.entity_id = ccev.entity_id
    WHERE cce.`level` = 3 and ccev.`attribute_id` = 41 and ccev.`store_id` = 0
    ORDER BY ccev.`value`
) r
on r.entity_id = cat.entity_id
set cat.`position` = (@rownum := @rownum + 1);
```